# What is the best way to save a psi4 molecule object in Python?

Tags: python, psi4

what is the best way to save and load a psi4 molecule? I tried pickle/dill but they both failed. I see a feature to save as xyz, but I'm not seeing a function to load as xyz and I'm not sure if save xyz also saves the energy and charges etc.

```
import psi4

# Define the molecular geometry using a string
h2_geometry = """
H 0.0 0.0 0.0
H 0.0 0.0 0.74
"""

# Create the molecule object
h2_molecule = psi4.geometry(h2_geometry)
```

```
pickle_file_path = "psi4_mol.pkl"
with open(pickle_file_path, 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(h2_molecule, file)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: cannot pickle 'psi4.core.Molecule' object
```

I also tried dill:

````
with open(pickle_file_path, 'wb') as file:
    dill.dump(h2_molecule, file)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "lib/python3.11/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 250, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol, **_kwds).dump(obj)
  File "lib/python3.11/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 418, in dump
    StockPickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "lib/python3.11/pickle.py", line 487, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "lib/python3.11/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "lib/python3.11/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "lib/python3.11/pickle.py", line 887, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "lib/python3.11/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 412, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "lib/python3.11/pickle.py", line 578, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot pickle 'psi4.core.Molecule' object
```
````

Comment: You may find the Psikit functions useful (https://github.com/Mishima-syk/psikit/blob/master/psikit/psikit.py). The GitHub repo hasn't been updated in quite some time, but the functions are pretty easily replicated (I'm planning to fork an update soon that plugs into py3Dmol on the other end).

Comment: Yes it's really interesting especially how it is integrating RDKit with Psi4, I was having trouble passing Psi4 to RDKit also. Thanks I will check it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need the geometry, molecular charge, and other related quantities, then `h2_geometry.to_dict()` is what you want. You can then save the returned `dict` with e.g. pickle.

If you also want to compute energies and such then save them to file, you want [`wfn.to_file`](https://psicode.org/psi4manual/master/api/psi4.core.Wavefunction.html#psi4.core.Wavefunction.to_file) and the partner function for loading, [`wfn.from_file`](https://psicode.org/psi4manual/master/api/psi4.core.Wavefunction.html#psi4.core.Wavefunction.from_file). These functions also generate (and read) `dict`s, which are serialized forms of the entire wavefunction. You may also pass an optional filename, which will save the wavefunction object as a `numpy` file.

You can get the wavefunction as a return from a calculation or building it yourself, e.g.

```
import psi4

mol = psi4.geometry("""
H 0.0 0.0 0.0
H 0.0 0.0 0.74""")

# build wfn yourself
bas = psi4.core.BasisSet.build(mol,"ORBITAL","sto-3g",quiet=True)
wfn = psi4.core.Wavefunction(mol,bas)

# get wfn as a return
psi4.set_options({"basis":"sto-3g"})
e,wfn = psi4.energy('scf',return_wfn=True)

# either way, save to file
wfn.to_file('wfn.npy')

# load it back up as a new wfn and print the variables inside
new_wfn = psi4.core.Wavefunction.from_file('wfn.npy')
print(new_wfn.variables())
```

Comment: But then how to reload it? I'm trying to save it so that I can come back to it later. If you append your answer to reload the psi4 from the file, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @Frank I believe that would just be the `psi4.core.Wavefunction.from_file` that Ben links to in their answer.

Comment: yes, `from_file` is what you need. I've added that to the answer.